# Html in translation files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5 with internationalization. Within the array where I store my key => values of all the languages used in the site I would like to add some html for styling the text:

lang_de.php

```
'error_message' => '<b>This is </b><br>a custom error<span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">message</span>',
```

This does not seem working for me. Any ideas what is wrong?

In my blade file I load it like this:

```
{!! trans('site.error_message') !!}
```

Thank you

Comment: how you are loading in blade?

Comment: {!! trans('site.error_message') !!}

Comment: When you pass your language files to others for translation are you sure you want them to have control over structure and style of your site? Can you be sure they will know HTML and CSS? I would urge you to keep your language files to language, not markup.

Comment: Oh definitely do not add markup to translation files!

Comment: How will then be possible to add som styling?

Comment: Putting style directly in language file is not better way as per my understanding, Language array key should hold the appropriate message related to that key

Comment: I understand that translation files should only contain the strings for holding the language. But has anyone an idea how I can use some markup for styling parts of the words of the sentence which is in the array?